# How to i get Dropdown selected item and value in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, dropdown

> How to i get this dropdown value to my controller in my model

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
      <label for="email" style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 18px;">Vendor Type:</label>
                                @Html.DropDownList("ActiveType", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.GetVendorType, new { id = "select2", @class = "select2_single form-control" })
                         </div>
```

Comment: It would help to show your `[HttpPost]` controller action.

Answer (score 0):

- Just add below line in controller action method (in POST method)

  ```
  var res = Request.Form["ActiveType"];
  ```

Comment: I also tried it but it was only return selected item, I want selected value also.